# Oracle APEX Dynamic action javaScript convert page item to array for value paired search

Tags: javascript, apex

I have a page item with the following value

`P10_PLOT_ARRAY := ‘{"plots":[{name:"Days on market Sydney (SUA) Houses", value:"Bar" }, {name:"Typical value Brisbane (SUA) Houses", value:"Bar" }, {name:"Typical value Melbourne (SUA) Houses", value:"Line" }]}’`

I am using the Dynamic action javescript to search a name and get the value as the following one I am expecting the value "Line"
But getting error as find is not a function how do I fix this.

```
let arr = $v('P10_PLOT_ARRAY'); 

 //apex.message.alert('array'+resultObject);
var value;
//var arr1 =JSON.parse(arr);  
  var b = arr.find(function(a) {
    return "Typical value Melbourne (SUA) Houses" === a.name;
  });
  apex.message.alert('value'+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `arr` is not an array, that's why it is not recognizing the method `find()` as dictated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). You need to specify that the array is the value of the key `"plots"`.

Also you can do some of these on the PL/SQL or SQL side.